# Can the alpha, lambda values of a glmnet object output determine whether ridge or Lasso?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, cross-validation, caret

Given a glmnet object using train() where  trControl method is "cv" and number of iterations is 5, I obtained that the bestTune alpha and lambda values are alpha=0.1 and lambda= 0.007688342. On running the glmnet object, I notice that the alpha values start from 0.1. 
Can the inference here be that the method used is Lasso and not ridge because of the non-negative alpha value?

In general, can the values of alpha, lambda indicate which model is being used?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand `glmnet`, $\alpha=0$ would actually be a ridge penalty, and $\alpha=1$ would be a Lasso penalty (rather than the other way around) and as far as `glmnet` is concerned you can fit those end cases.

The penalty with $\alpha=0.1$ would be fairly similar to the ridge penalty but it is not the ridge penalty; if it's not considering $\alpha$ below $0.1$ you can't necessarily infer much more than that just from the fact that you had that endpoint. If you know that an $\alpha$ value that was only slightly larger was worse then it would be likely that a larger range might have chosen a smaller $\alpha$, but it doesn't suggest it would have been $0$; I expect it would not. If the grid of values is coarse it may well have been that a larger value than $0.1$ would be better.

[You may want to check whether there was some other reason that $\alpha$ might have been at an endpoint; e.g. I seem to recall $\lambda$ got set to an endpoint in forecasting if coefficients for `lambdaOpt` were not saved.]

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely! The $\alpha$ parameter can be adjusted to either fit a Lasso or a Ridge regression (or something in between). Recall that the loss function which Elastic Net minimizes is $$\frac{1}{2N}\sum^N_{i=1}(y_i-\beta_0-x_i^t\beta)^2+\lambda\sum_{j=1}^p(\frac{1}{2}(1-\alpha)\beta_j^2+\alpha|\beta_j|).$$
Focus on the second big sum (the one multiplied by $\lambda$). If you let $\alpha=1$, the first term inside this sum becomes $0$, and the whole function becomes exactly the function that Lasso minimizes (or the Lasso loss function). If you let $\alpha=0$, the second term becomes $0$ and you are left with Ridge.

You can check the loss for Ridge and Lasso in [this book](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) (An Introduction to statistical learning with applications in R by James, Witten, Hastie and Tibshirani) and for elastic net in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20808728) (Regularization paths for generalized linear models via coordinate descent by Friedman, Hastie and Tibshirani).

Comment: This looks like a good answer but can you edit to include citations for the hyperlinks? Over time, links die.